# Bootstrap problems with grid system

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, I was studying the front-end course which was created in 2018 and this guy Brad Hussey was teaching Bootstrap, and when I downloaded the source code and everything to make the website work, the grid system for example was not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap Forms</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Bootstrap Forms</h1>
            <p class="lead">Let's work with some sexy, pre-styled forms, shall we?</p>
        </div><!-- page-header -->
            
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">     
            </div>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your bootstrap version ?

Comment: my bootstrap version is 3.3.5

Answer (score 0):

You're missing closing div tags. Other than that it seems to work alright.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Forms</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">              <!--- you never closed --->
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Bootstrap Forms</h1>
            <p class="lead">Let's work with some sexy, pre-styled forms, shall we?</p>
        </div><!-- page-header -->  
        <div class="row">            <!--- you never closed --->
            <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            </div>
         </div> <!--- add </div> here --->
</div> <!--- add div here --->
                  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
                  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
             <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```